# Email Alert using VisualForce Email Template Produces Empty Email

Tags: visualforce, workflow, email-template, email-alert

I want to send an email on creation of a record. The email must contain information about the record plus certain related detail records. I chose a VisualForce email template with a VF component referenced by the template to meed this requirement.

My email template works when I press the test button and enter the ID of a certain record. The template renders the data and I receive a test email just as I want.

I setup a workflow action, an Email Alert, referencing this template and the custom object type. I receive an email however, there's no body, it's blank.

I checked the debug logs and there's nothing there saying the APEX code threw an exception. Something must have gone wrong though I don't know what. I'm guessing the id of the custom record is not being passed to the template.

is a VisualForce template containing a component. On the test page for the template, I can click the 'test' button and enter a record ID and tick the 'send a test email'. The template renders and I receive the test email as expected.

Is this even possible?
How do I troubleshoot the problem?

VisualForce Component Controller:

```
public with sharing class LicensePropertiesComponentController {

    public LicensePropertiesComponentController() {
    }

    public ID getId() {
        return m_licenseId;
    }

    public void setId(ID value) {
        m_licenseId = value;
    }

    public List<String> getLines() {
        List<String> lines = new List<String>();
        try {
            Initialize();
                for (LicenseProperty__c property :m_properties) {
                    label = isNull(property.LabelText__c, 'No Label');
                    value = isNull(property.Value__c, 'No Value');
                    lines.add(String.format('{0} ... {1}', new String[]{label, value}));
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            lines.add('An exception occurred: ' + ex);
            System.debug(ex);
        }
        return lines;
    }

    private ID m_licenseId;
    private List<LicenseProperty__c> m_properties;

    private void initialize() {
        try {
            m_properties = [SELECT Group1Order__c, Group2Order__c, Group3Order__c, DisplayOrder__c, Group1Name__c, Group2Name__c, Group3Name__c, LabelText__c, Value__c, License__c FROM LicenseProperty__c WHERE License__r.ID = :m_licenseId ORDER BY Group1Order__c, Group2Order__c, Group3Order__c, DisplayOrder__c];
        }catch(Exception ex) {
        }  
    }

    private string isNull(string input, string substitute) {
        if (input == null) return substitute;
        return input;
    }

    private decimal isNull(decimal input, decimal substitute) {
        if (input == null) return substitute;
        return input;
    }
}
```

The APEX component:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="LicensePropertiesComponentController">
    <apex:attribute name="licenseId" description="Object ID of License__c instance whos properties will be rendered." type="ID" required="required" assignTo="{!id}" />
    <apex:repeat id="repCtrl" var="line" value="{!Lines}">
{!line}
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

The next bit

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="License Request" recipientType="User" relatedToType="License__c">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
<c:LicensePropertiesComponent licenseId="{!relatedTo.ID}" />
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

That's all for now.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/parameter-not-being-passed-in-visualforce-template   Something like this should help you debug

Comment: My database SOQL queries are not being done in the constructor of the VF component; I've been bitten by that before.

Comment: There's a try/catch with catch block System.debug logging around the data access code plus the code that processes the data. Nothing's logged.

Comment: share your code please on question

Comment: if a field update is part of your workflow - then this might help http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22568/approval-process-step-field-update-doesnt-appear-in-same-steps-visualforce-ema (although the psot is about approval processes, I was told by sfdc support that it is true for workflows but have not verified that)

Comment: What is the significance of the API Version? Most of my custom artefacts are version 30.0 but a few are now 31.0. This afternoon, the template above started working, firing emails with the expected body content - even though I thought the workflow rule was disabled.

Comment: I changed the implementation of LicensePropertiesComponentController to produce a HTML document instead of a bunch of text lines, and re-ran my test. Instead of producing an email with the new HTML content, the email contained the old line-by-line content. I think it would be best if I could somehow pull up all my custom artefacts to version 31.0 but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: @IanT8 i am facing the same issue. Can you guide me how did you overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

OK, this could be the issue (having recently faced this myself)

Your database structure appears to be:

- `License__c`
- Several `License_Property__c` each of which has a lookup relationship to `License__c`

You mentioned that you are using a workflow to fire the email alert that references the `License__c`. The target of the workflow, is represented in the VF email template by `relatedTo.id`

- Per VF order of execution, `relatedTo.id` is passed as an attribute to the custom component and assigned to the custom controller's `m_licenseId` via the `setId()` method
- The order of execution now has the component calling `getLines()` that calls `Initialize()` to fetch the list of `License_property__c`

So far, so good.

My hypothesis, and where I was bitten, is when you test the template in the VF Email Template editor, you already had built the `License__c` and related `License_Property__c`s. The template renders fine

But when you test via exercising the workflow, no `License_property__c`s appear

A likely cause of this is that the workflow is triggered too soon - before the `License_Property__c` are built by whatever process causes the workflow on `License__c` to fire.  Check your workflow entry criteria versus the state of the database.